# Joining two tables data based on two columns in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

There is data coming from two different tables(expiry and delete). i want to show results (in SSRS )joined from these two tables based on company name and month/date. So resultset should look like this:
[image]

The heading(1,2,3 are jan,feb,march). similary the other report is for daily basis(1,2,3 are dated for same month). expiry units and expiry revenue is from table expiry.delete units and delete revenue is from delete table. how to join these based on organization and dates/month.
thanks.

Comment: Share the datasets in order to help you. You can use `Lookup` function to join datasets.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta i tried it but not getting correct results. can you please give example for that. Thanks

Comment: Examples may vary based on the data. This is an example of lookup usage `Lookup(Fields!ExpiryCompany.Value,Fields!DeleteCompany.Value,Fields!DeleteUnits.Value,"DataSetDelete")`. This expression will return the `DeleteUnits` when `ExpiryCompany` is equal to `DeleteCompany`.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta  But there are two column based on which it needs to be matched. one is company other is date.

Comment: Create a calculated field in both datasets like this: `=Fields!Company.Value & "-" & Fields!Month.Value` Then use `Lookup(Fields!CalculatedField.Value,Fields!CalculatedField.Value,Fields!DeleteUnits‌​.Value,"DataSetDelete")`